# Wsadmin script for MailSession at server level

Tags: websphere, admin, jython, wsadmin

I'm not able to figure out how to create a Mail Session at server level.

This is my calling script:

```
WasLib.createMailSession("MY_MAIL_SESSION","mail/Emailer","smtp-myserver.com", "", "", "")
```

This script existing script creates the mail session at the cell level but I need to change the scope to server level. So far, I have been forced to recreate the Mail Session manually everytime I run my script.

This is my WasLib.createMailSession function:

```
def createMailSession(sessionName, jndiName, mailTransportHost, mailTransportUser, mailTransportPassword, mailFrom):
    print 'Creation du Mail Session : ' + sessionName
    name = ['name', sessionName ]
    jndi = ['jndiName', jndiName ]
    host = ['mailTransportHost', mailTransportHost ]
    user = ['mailTransportUser', mailTransportUser ]
    password = ['mailTransportPassword', mailTransportPassword ]
    mFrom = ['mailFrom', mailFrom ]
    protocol = ['mailTransportProtocol', getProtocolProvider('smtp') ]
    debug = ['debug', "true" ]
    strict = ['strict', "true" ]
    mailAttrs = [ name, jndi, host, user, password, mFrom, protocol, debug, strict ]
    #print "attributes" + AdminConfig.attributes('MailSession')
    #print "Required " + AdminConfig.required('MailSession')
        mailSession = AdminConfig.create('MailSession', **getMailProvider()**, mailAttrs)

    if (mailTransportUser != "") :
        for itemId in AdminConfig.list('J2EEResourcePropertySet', mailSession).split(lineSeparator) :
            if len(itemId) == 0 :
                itemId = AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourcePropertySet', mailSession, "[]")
            AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', itemId, '[[name "mail.smtp.port"] [type "java.lang.String"] [description ""] [value "587"] [required "false"]]')
                AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', itemId, '[[name "mail.smtp.auth"] [type "java.lang.String"] [description ""] [value "true"] [required "false"]]')
                AdminConfig.create('J2EEResourceProperty', itemId, '[[name "mail.smtp.from"] [type "java.lang.String"] [description ""] [value "' + mailFrom + '"] [required "false"]]')
                #endIf
            #endFor
        #endIf
        return mailSession
#endDef
```

As you can see getMailProvider returns the cell, when I change it to server, it fails.

```
def getMailProvider():
    return AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:'+AdminControl.getCell()+'/MailProvider:Built-in Mail Provider/')
#endDef
```

I have tried this with no luck:

```
def getMailProvider():
    return AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:'+ AdminControl.getCell() 
 +'/Node:'+    AdminControl.getNode() +'/Server:'+ getServer() +'/')    
#endDef
```

Comment: You are missing `+'/MailProvider:Built-in Mail Provider/'` in the second example. Is it a typo or you forgot about it? :-)

Comment: As this `AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + AdminControl.getCell() + '/Node:' + AdminControl.getNode() + '/Server:server1' + '/MailProvider:Built-in Mail Provider/')` works for me.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. It solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `+'/MailProvider:Built-in Mail Provider/'` in the second example.

The full command should be:

`AdminConfig.getid('/Cell:' + AdminControl.getCell() + '/Node:' + AdminControl.getNode() + '/Server:server1' + '/MailProvider:Built-in Mail Provider/')`